# how to I change the owner of a folder on my server?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, owner

OK I'll be more specific - I have uploaded a bunch of folders via ftp. These now all have the the owner name of the account which I logged into FTP using.

**How do I change the owner to be the server name?**

and

**How do I find out what name the server is using?**

I'm pretty new to server permissions and the like, so please be gentle :) BTW, I'm using a linux server.

Comment: W​h​ich server?

Comment: not sure. Surely the commands are the same if its a linux server?

Comment: Web server? FTP server? Samba server?

Comment: Do you have access to the root account ?

Comment: this might be a question (or rather 2 questions) better asked  on superuser.com. I think they're also a little more gentle there...

Answer (score 1):

To change the owner of a file or dir you can use the "chown" command.

To view the name of the server use the "hostname" command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "hostname" command to find the server name,

I don't really userstand your first question, you can't manage permissions by hosts, it's per users/groups

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an FTP client like [Filezila](http://filezilla-project.org/), I don't believe you can change the owner of the file through its interface.

If you have SSH access to the server using a program like [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), then you can use the `chown` command as Kedare suggested.

In order to change the hostname, it depends on which distro of Linux you're using if you're using linux. Also, make sure you're not confusing hostname with domain name. And usually, you'll need to be root to change the hostname if it is linux.

If you are using a debian based distro such as Ubuntu, you can edit the /etc/hostname file and replace the current value with what you want to call your server.

If you need more help, please post more details.